# Meaning of かって and general sense of this sentence

Tags: meaning

Though the  speaker is supposed to support her boyfriend who is fighting, she looks like she supports his opponent. Another character then says to her :

> おまえ　なにいってんだよ　ボーイフレンドだろ...！
>
> Just what are you saying? That's your boyfriend isn't it?

She responds :

> いいじゃない　べつにあこがれるぐらいかってでしょ！
>
> Yeah, yeah, give me a break. [?]

I'm a bit lost there, I'm used to see べつに in negative sentences, and I don't see what かって means here... I suspect the end of the sentence is omitted but I can't figure out what the omitted part would be...

Comment: There is a fairly big difference in meaning/nuance between the "dictionary" 「別に」 and the slangy 「別に」 (and you are clearly 'seeing' the former).  The latter does not need to take a negative phrase following it.

Comment: Do you mean I'm seeing the former though it's the latter or that it's the former that can be seen here? : ) Is the slangy べつに you mention something vague like "Whatever/I don't really care" in english?

Comment: I am saying that you are 'seeing' the former when it is not the case.  (At least, that is what I think from reading your question.  I could be wrong, though.) The colloquial/slangy meaning is much like "meh".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"勝手(かって)" in this case means "license" and " abandon ", "one's own way", etc. For example, 私のかって means "That is my choice" and " As I please",etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still lost regarding the general meaning of the sentence... If the general idea is "Whatever, I do what I want!", I don't see how あこがれるぐらい fit in that...

Comment: For example,  The one said 彼には恋人がいるよ(He has a girl friend.). She answered あこがれるぐらいは勝手でしょ。(Only yearning is license, isn't it?). And We can use ～するぐらいは自由でしょ and ～するぐらいは良いでしょ instead of ～するぐらい勝手でしょ.

Comment: So, that would be something like "I can at least admire the other(s) as I want can't I?"

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: If you could comment on how べつに affects the rest of the statement, it would make your answer more complete.

Comment: べつに is sometimes used as interjection like indifference and abandonment. I think べつに is used as abandonment in this case like べつに勝手でしょ.